# Maior espaço entre os itens do spinner

Tags: android, android-layout, spinners

Estou criando um app que possui spinner, porem ao abrir os itens estão sempre colados uns nos outros, gostaria de saber se apenas por custom spinner eu consigo dar espaço ou existe algum style/tema que ja possua esses espaços...as classe e tudo ja está criado só falta o layout funcional ao abrir o spinner

Comment: Aleff, como está montando o layout dos seus itens? em geral basta adicionar um padding para dar um espaçamento...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode mudar a aparência do seu spinner mudando o adaptador que foi usado para o mesmo com o seguinte comando:

```
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

O **simple_spinner_dropdown_item** é o layout padrão para spinners. Creio que seja isso que procuras. Se preferires podes também [criar um estilo customizado](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694786/how-to-customize-a-spinner-in-android).

Answer (score 1):

Crie o seu próprio adapter, assim você pode customizar da forma que preferir.

Exemplo:

public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
public ListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
    super(context, R.id.campotexto);
}

public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Item> items) {
    super(context, resource, items);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi;
        vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.linhacustomizada, null);
    }

    Item p = getItem(position);

    if (p != null) {
        TextView tt1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.id);
        TextView tt2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.categoryId);
        TextView tt3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.description);

        if (tt1 != null) {
            tt1.setText(p.getId());
        }

        if (tt2 != null) {
            tt2.setText(p.getCategory().getId());
        }

        if (tt3 != null) {
            tt3.setText(p.getDescription());
        }
    }

    return v;
}
```

}